# PHP Script Memory Leak

Tags: php, memory-leaks

I understand this isn't exactly the smallest code, i've tried to cut it down as much as i could. The script just consumes more and more memory until it finally runs out. I've used unset() where possible but it doesn't seem to have any effect. It always seems to error in the MultiGet function but i'm not sure if that is where the leak is. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
public function Test()
{
    $base = dirname(__FILE__) .'/';
    $prod_file = $base.'products.dbf';

    $this->dbf->load($prod_file);
    $num_rec=$ci->dbf->dbf_num_rec;

    $buffer = Array();
    for($i=0;$i<$num_rec;$i++):
        $row = $ci->dbf->getRowAssoc($i);

        $info = Array('part_number' => $row['PART_NUM'],
                      'td_group_id' => $row['GRP'],
                      'name' => 'DESCR');

        $this->db->where('td_group_id',$info['td_group_id']);
        $result = $this->db->get('tbl_categories')->row_array();
        if(isset($result['id'])):
            $info['category_id'] = $result['id'];
            $buffer[]  = $info;
        endif;

        if(count($buffer) == 100 || $i == $num_rec -1):
            $url_buffer = Array();
            foreach($buffer as $row):
                $url_buffer[] = $this->_product_url($row['part_number']);
            endforeach;

            $html_returns = $this->MultiCrawl($url_buffer);
            foreach($html_returns as $url_index=>$html):
                $more_info = $this->_extract_more_info($html);
                if($more_info):
                    $more_info['category_id'] = $buffer[$url_index]['category_id'];
                    $more_info['td_part_number'] = $buffer[$url_index]['part_number'];
                    $this->_parse_product($more_info);
                endif;
            endforeach;
            $buffer = Array();
        endif;

    endfor;



}


function MultiGet($all_urls)
{

    $useragent = $this->_useragent;
    $cookie_file = $this->_cookie_file;

    $url_index = $this->UrlIndex($all_urls);

    $return_buffer = Array();

    $mh = curl_multi_init();

    $ch = Array();
    $max_connections = 15;
    $index = 0;
    $open_connections = 0;
    $execReturnValue = true;
    $running = true;
    $max_index = count($all_urls)-1;
    $url_count = count($all_urls);
    $buffer_count = 0;

    while ($buffer_count < $url_count){

        if($open_connections < $max_connections && $index <= $max_index):
            for($i=$open_connections;$i<$max_connections && $index <= $max_index;$i++):
                $url = $all_urls[$index];
                $ch[$index] = curl_init($url);
                curl_setopt($ch[$index],CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                curl_setopt($ch[$index],CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch[$index],CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false);
                curl_setopt($ch[$index],CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST , false);
                curl_setopt($ch[$index],CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false);
                curl_setopt($ch[$index],CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
                curl_setopt($ch[$index],CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
                curl_setopt($ch[$index],CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$useragent);
                curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$index]);
                $open_connections++;
                $index++;
                $execReturnValue = curl_multi_exec($mh,$running);
                usleep(200);
            endfor;
        endif;

        $execReturnValue = curl_multi_exec($mh,$running);
        $ready=curl_multi_select($mh);


        while($info=curl_multi_info_read($mh)){
            $status=curl_getinfo($info['handle'],CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            if($status==200){
                $successUrl=curl_getinfo($info['handle'],CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
                $curl_index = $url_index[$successUrl];
                $return_buffer[$curl_index] = curl_multi_getcontent($ch[$curl_index]);
                $buffer_count = count($return_buffer);
                curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch[$curl_index]);
                curl_close($ch[$curl_index]);
                unset($ch[$curl_index]);
                $open_connections--;
            }else{

                echo "ERROR: $status\n";
            }
        }
    } 

    curl_multi_close($mh);
    unset($mh);

    return $return_buffer;
}



private function _extract_more_info($html)
{

    $buffer = array();


    $query = "//img[@id='ctl00_cphMain_cntrlProductProfile_imgprodimage']";
    $result = $this->_xquery($html,$query);
    $node = $result instanceof DOMNode?$this->_to_dom_node($result):null;
    if(!$node) return null;
    $buffer['td_img_url'] = $node?trim($node->getAttribute('src')):null;
    unset($result);


    $query = "//span[@class='priceLarge']";
    $result = $this->_xquery($html,$query);
    $node = $result instanceof DOMNode?$this->_to_dom_node($result):null;
    if(!$node) return null;
    $buffer['price'] = $node?trim($node->nodeValue):null;
    if($buffer['price'] == 'Req. Auth.') return null;
    unset($result);


    $query = "//span[@id='ctl00_cphMain_cntrlProductProfile_newLtFinalPrice']";
    $result = $this->_xquery($html,$query);
    $node = $result instanceof DOMNode?$this->_to_dom_node($result):null;
    if(!$node) return null;
    $buffer['msrp'] = $node?trim($node->nodeValue):null;
    unset($result);


    $query = "//span[@id='ctl00_cphMain_cntrlProductProfile_newLTMRF']";
    $result = $this->_xquery($html,$query);
    $node = $result instanceof DOMNode?$this->_to_dom_node($result):null;
    if(!$node) return null;
    $buffer['manf_part_number'] = $node?trim($node->nodeValue):null;
    unset($result);


    $query = "//span[@id='ctl00_cphMain_cntrlProductProfile_newLblUPC']";
    $result = $this->_xquery($html,$query);
    $node = $result instanceof DOMNode?$this->_to_dom_node($result):null;
    $buffer['upc_part_number'] = $node?trim($node->nodeValue):null;
    unset($result);


    $query = "//td[@class='black_text_WUL']";
    $result = $this->_xquery($html,$query);
    $node = $result instanceof DOMNode?$this->_to_dom_node($result):null;
    if(!$node) return null;
    $buffer['manufacturer'] = $node?trim($node->nodeValue):null;
    unset($result);


    $query = "//td[@class='textt' and @colspan='3']";
    $result = $this->_xquery($html,$query);
    $node = $result instanceof DOMNode?$this->_to_dom_node($result):null;
    if(!$node) return null;
    $buffer['short_description'] = $node?trim($node->nodeValue):null;
    unset($result);





    $query = "//div[@id='ctl00_cphMain_pnlMarketingDesc']//td[@class='textt']";
    $result = $this->_xquery($html,$query);
    $node = $result instanceof DOMNode?$this->_to_dom_node($result):null;
    if(!$node) return null;
    $buffer['long_description'] = $node?trim($node->nodeValue):null;
    unset($result);

    $query = "//table[@id='ctl00_cphMain_cntrlMainSpecs_dgSpecs']";
    $result = $this->_xquery($html,$query);
    $table = $result instanceof DOMNode?$this->_to_dom_node($result):null;
    unset($result);

    if(!$table) return null;
    $table_array = Array();
    $rows = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr');
    foreach($rows as $tr):
        $temp = Array();
        $columns = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td');
        $caption = $columns->length > 0 && $columns->length <= 2 ? trim($columns->item(0)->nodeValue) : null;
        $value = $columns->length == 2 ? trim($columns->item(1)->nodeValue) : null;

        if ($caption) $table_array[$caption] = $value;
    endforeach;


    $buffer['main_specs']=$table_array;


    $query = "//table[@id='ctl00_cphMain_cntrlExtSpecs_tblData']";
    $result = $this->_xquery($html,$query);
    $table = $result instanceof DOMNode?$this->_to_dom_node($result):null;
    unset($result);
    $buffer['additional_specs'] = null;
    if(!$table) return $buffer;


    $table_array = Array();
    $rows = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr');
    foreach($rows as $tr):
        $temp = Array();
        $columns = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td');
        $caption = $columns->length > 0 && $columns->length <= 2 ? trim($columns->item(0)->nodeValue) : null;
        $value = $columns->length == 2 ? trim($columns->item(1)->nodeValue) : null;

        if ($caption) $table_array[$caption] = $value;
    endforeach;
    $buffer['additional_specs']=$table_array;;
    return $buffer;

}



private function _xquery($html,$query,$allnodes = false){
    $src = '';
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $node = null;
    if (@$dom->loadHTML($html)) {
        $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
        $nodeList = $xpath->query($query);
        if ($nodeList->length > 0) {
            $node = $allnodes==false?$nodeList->item(0):$nodeList;
        }
    }
    unset($xpath);
    unset($nodeList);
    unset($dom);
    return $node;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a leak, or does it just need more memory?

Comment: How much memory is it consuming before php services are shut down and what is the maximum amount of data you expect to be stored at any given time?

Comment: I believe it's a leak as I unset any variables where I can. It gets up to 100mb+ in memory usage. None of the pages are that big nor am I storing that much data in any variables.

Comment: @65Fbef05: I'm running the script again to get an exact number for you. My memory_limit is set to 128M

Comment: I don't think you " tried to cut it down as much as i could" lol

Comment: What is the entry point?  Which function gets called?

Comment: @yes123: I suppose I could have stripped more similar lines in some of the functions but I wanted to give as much relevant info as I could.

Comment: Some more numbers would be convenient, too: how many rows in the db, how many bytes in a row, ....

Comment: @xtofl: "Test" is the first function to be called. The db has 65k rows and 8 fields with a combined length of about 150 chars.

Comment: I get through about 1.5k records before it runs out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Strategies to find a leak?

- make sure it *is* a leak (if processing 1/100 of the data, is memory still not freed? 1/1000?)
- think about complexity: if `foo` is O(n), `bar` is O(n) and `bar` calls `foo`, the result may become O(n*n).
- experiment: disable parts of the program until it leaks no more

At first sight, you're crawling a series of url's.  These may contain more url's, to be crawled using the `MultiCrawl` method.  Are you sure there can't be a cycle in there?  (working with folders has tricked me more than once: browsing '.' as a subfolder yields infinite loops)

Comment: It doesn't do any depth. I have a dbf of product numbers/prices. It uses the product number to go to the distributors site to grab some additional information.